# Python loop not providing expected output

Tags: python

Here is a python while loop code I am using:

```
i = 0.0
while i < 9.0:
    y = 13.0 - i
    if (y -i) == 6.0:
        print '[+] Solution found!'
        print 'x = ', i
        print 'y = ', y
        print 'z =', 8.0 - i
    i += 0.1
```

The problem is that 'if' block never gets executed even when condition is satisfied. On the other hand, if I put increment of 0.5 i.e. `i += 0.5` then the code works as it should. Any idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: are you using python 2 ? I'd suggest switching for python3, for which the syntax is different concerning print statements. Plus, in your example, i is not defined

Comment: yeah I am using python 2 and it is not related to printing

Comment: What is the initial value of 'i'?

Comment: would it be ok to switch to python 3 ? And i is undefined

Comment: Type printing the values of `i` outside the `if` then see: [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: @RalviIsufaj sorry for that...initial value of i is 0.0.

Comment: @MarkMeyer tried that already and everything seems fine

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about floating point math in Python. Use a library such as decimal for operations.

Comment: Due to limited, floating point precision ``y - i - i`` will be ``5.9999999999999964``, not ``6.0``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi when printing the values of `i`, `y` & `y - i`, `y - i` is correctly displayed as 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code :

```
i = 0.0
while i < 9.0:
    y = 13.0 - i
    if round((y -i),1) == 6.0:
        print('[+] Solution found!')
        print('x = ', round(i,1))
        print('y = ', round(y,1))
        print('z =', round(8.0 - i,1))
    i += 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of floating point precision. It's a really old problem. A way to get around this is to use Decimal and limit the precision to 2 digits after the comma. A possible way would like this (switched to python3 to test on my machine):

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
i = Decimal(0.0)
while i < Decimal(9.0):
    y = Decimal(13.0) - i
    if (y -i) == 6.0:
        print('[+] Solution found!')
        print('x = ', i)
        print('y = ', y)
        print('z =', Decimal(8.0) - i)
    i += Decimal(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by floating point precision. As MisterMiyagi commented, check [Is floating point math broken ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10860121). I would suggest using integers here.